# How to interpret Cloudflare's SVCB/HTTPS DNS record type?

Tags: https, dns

From a recent article of Cloudflare adding SVCB/HTTPS DNS records automatically, I'm trying to interpret what they're publishing in the DNS record.

The current draft for SVCB or HTTPS seems to be "draft-ietf-dnsop-svcb-https-01".

Using dig to get cloudflare blog's DNS record:

```
dig blog.cloudflare.com -t TYPE65
```

Answer to the query:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
blog.cloudflare.com.    300 IN  TYPE65  \# 76 000100000100150568332D32390568332D32380568332D3237026832 0004000868121A2E68121B2E00060020260647000000000000000000 68121A2E26064700000000000000000068121B2E
```

Returns a RFC3597 encoded format of the answer.

It would be nice to know what it says. What does it say?

Answer (score 8):

The `drill` command supports HTTPS RR (type 65) in the latest git revision [1]. To use it, build ldns with `--enable-rrtype-svcb-https`. Here are example usages:

```
$ drill HTTPS blog.cloudflare.com | grep ^blog
blog.cloudflare.com.    300     IN      HTTPS   1 . alpn=h3-29,h3-28,h3-27,h2 ipv4hint=104.18.26.46,104.18.27.46 ipv6hint=2606:4700::6812:1a2e,2606:4700::6812:1b2e

$ drill HTTPS crypto.cloudflare.com | grep ^crypto
crypto.cloudflare.com.  237     IN      HTTPS   1 . alpn=h2 ipv4hint=162.159.135.79,162.159.136.79 echconfig=AEj+CgBEhwAgACA8RalVTTRgfQYqMSqwX4GiBa6kftXcUcQZIkqhwe0PLwAEAAEAAQAAABNjbG91ZGZsYXJlLWVzbmkuY29tAAA= ipv6hint=2606:4700:7::a29f:874f,2606:4700:7::a29f:884f
```

Update 2021/09/05: dig now also supports HTTPS records in the latest git revision [2]. Here are example usages:

```
$ dig HTTPS blog.cloudflare.com | grep ^blog    
blog.cloudflare.com.    242     IN      HTTPS   1 . alpn="h3,h3-29,h3-28,h3-27,h2" ipv4hint=104.18.26.46,104.18.27.46 ipv6hint=2606:4700::6812:1a2e,2606:4700::6812:1b2e

$ dig HTTPS crypto.cloudflare.com | grep ^crypto
crypto.cloudflare.com.  285     IN      HTTPS   1 . alpn="h2" ipv4hint=162.159.135.79,162.159.136.79 ech=AEb+DQBCmwAgACA5ysTCbPox2yTLTsrGuJ8QHfwHjqZLcNGTA7xAiBJNSQAEAAEAAQATY2xvdWRmbGFyZS1lc25pLmNvbQAA ipv6hint=2606:4700:7::a29f:874f,2606:4700:7::a29f:884f
```

[1] https://github.com/NLnetLabs/ldns/pull/115

[2] https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/merge_requests/2135

Comment: The `dnscrypt-proxy -resolve` command also displays HTTPS records by default.

Comment: The drill binary on Ubuntu 23.04 now supports the HTTPS dns record. Compiling drill is an nightmare so the easiest way to get that binary is `sudo docker run -it ubuntu:devel bash`

Answer (score 4):

I managed to manually decode the first part of it:

```
\# 76 total length
0001 priority
00 full registered name, null, "."
0001 alpn key type
0015 alpn value length
05 alpn-id length
68332D3239 alpn-id: h3-29
05 alpn-id length
68332D3238 alpn-id: h3-28
05 alpn-id length
68332D3237 alpn-id: h3-27
02 alpn-id length
6832 alpn-id: h2
```

Maybe I'll work through the rest later, but interesting to see the h3-29, 28, and 27 ALPN types.

I also found that dnspython has support for the record type in master, and some other software does to according to this list: https://github.com/MikeBishop/dns-alt-svc/blob/master/svcb-implementations.md

Answer (score 4):

Wireshark 3.4.0 seems to now have support for decoding HTTPS records if you can take a packet capture.

It shows me that Cloudflare are providing IPv4 and IPv6 hints as well as the ALPN information.

Comment: Thanks for the update! If you could include a copy of some output I think that would be helpful to others besides the raw notes in the other response.